# Site to browse/get eclipse formatter profiles

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Is there a site where Eclipse formatter profiles are loaded with the type of results they produce are shown?
Something like http://studiostyl.es/ except for Eclipse formatter profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ is a good site for themes, formatting I dont think there is is a site for those since most people just go with Java Conventions [built-in]